Using destination file name vs destination directory when moving a file creates auditd logging dilemma
I am trying to log file operations using auditd (audit 4.0.1) and came across an issue with moving files. If I include the filename in the destination:
mv /mnt/user/home/file.txt /mnt/user/home/Folder1/file.txt

I get this:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): syscall=264 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffcad79d745 a2=ffffff9c a3=7ffcad79d763 items=4 ppid=402506 pid=763811 comm="mv" exe="/bin/mv" SYSCALL=renameat 
type=CWD msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): cwd="/usr/local"
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): item=0 name="/mnt/user/home/Folder1/" inode=11540474087238444 nametype=PARENT 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): item=1 name="/mnt/user/home/" inode=11540474084530994 nametype=PARENT 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): item=2 name="/mnt/user/home/file.txt" inode=652740471477682549 nametype=DELETE 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): item=3 name="/mnt/user/home/Folder1/file.txt" inode=652740471477682549 nametype=CREATE 
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1723755217.700:367): proctitle=mv /mnt/user/home/file.txt /mnt/user/home/Folder1/file.txt
type=EOE msg=audit(1723755217.700:367):

But if I just include the destination folder:
mv /mnt/user/home/file.txt /mnt/user/home/Folder1/

I get two syscalls:
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1723755697.454:465): syscall=257 success=yes exit=3 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffc55b2276c a2=210000 a3=0 items=1 comm="mv" exe="/bin/mv" SYSCALL=openat 
type=CWD msg=audit(1723755697.454:465): cwd="/usr/local"
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755697.454:465): item=0 name="/mnt/user/home/Folder1/" inode=11540474087238444 nametype=NORMAL 
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1723755697.454:465): proctitle=mv /mnt/user/home/file.txt /mnt/user/home/Folder1/
type=EOE msg=audit(1723755697.454:465):

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): syscall=264 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffff9c a1=7ffc55b2274a a2=3 a3=4270fa items=4 comm="mv" exe="/bin/mv" SYSCALL=renameat 
type=CWD msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): cwd="/usr/local"
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): item=0 name="/usr/local" inode=11540474087238444 nametype=PARENT 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): item=1 name="/mnt/user/home/" inode=11540474084530994 nametype=PARENT 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): item=2 name="/mnt/user/home/file.txt" inode=652740471477682549 nametype=DELETE 
type=PATH msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): item=3 name="file.txt" inode=652740471477682549 nametype=CREATE 
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1723755697.455:466): proctitle=mv /mnt/user/home/file.txt /mnt/user/home/Folder1/
type=EOE msg=audit(1723755697.455:466):

Using a directory as the destination and not including a filename means it will just keep the same filename but then I am unsure how to parse this scenario. The first scenario is easy, items 2 and 3 are the source and destination. The second scenario creates an openat syscall and then a renameat syscall and the renameat syscall is structured differently. None of the items have the destination directory; that's in the openat syscall. I wasn't planning on including openat in my audit rules because I didn't need it and there are just way too many calls anyway. But now I have to figure out how to handle this odd-ball scenario. I haven't been able to find any solutions from others that might have encountered this. Here is the rule I used, the only one:
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S all -F dir=/mnt/user/home/ -F success=1

I had to broaden it to troubleshoot because as I said, I wasn't looking for openat syscalls. The only thing I can think of is to include openat and somehow link the openat and renameat syscalls, filtering out any openat calls that don't match. But the issue with that is my scripts currently work on a per event basis, and this is two events. I'm sure there are more issues I haven't even thought of. Any ideas on how to handle this?

I think whether intention or not, this is how it works. I would consider this a bug but I posted on the github page about it so I don't think there is anything to be done.
